# LINQ Group Nested List To Restructure Data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a nested list of a custom object passed from a service as JSON that I need to restructure into a new object. Here is the object that the nested list consists of:

```
public class Alt
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Claim OriginalClaim { get; set; }
    public Claim AltClaim { get; set; }
    public double Savings { get; set; }
}
```

For each Member and OriginalClaim, there can be one or more AltClaim. So what I'm trying to do is get every AltClaim for each Member/OriginalClaim. The new object that I will be mapping the data to looks like this:

```
public class Alternative
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Claim OriginalClaim { get; set; }
    public List<AlternativeClaim> AlternativeClaims { get; set; }
}

public class AlternativeClaim
{
    public Claim AltClaim { get; set; }
    public double Savings { get; set; }
}
```

I've been able to get things grouped via LINQ, but it is producing a list of Alternative with the Member and OriginalClaim duplicated as many times as there are AlternativeClaims. Here is the code I've got so far:

```
public void Test(List<List<Alt>> alternatives)
{
    var test = from alts in alternatives
               from alt in alts
               group alts by new { alt.Member, alt.OriginalClaim } into a
               select a;

    foreach (var a in test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Auth {0}", a.Key.OriginalClaim.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("MemberId {0}", a.Key.Member.Id);

        foreach (var alt in a.SelectMany(x => x))
        {
            [write out alt.AltClaim properties in console here]
        }
    }
}
```

I believe my issue is with the LINQ query. I'm not terribly familiar with LINQ, so is there anyone out there that can help me form this (or at least point me in the right direction) so I don't get the duplicates? Thanks!!

**EDIT (SOLUTION):**

The solution that worked for me was a combination of two answers below. [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28951682/1458847) is the LINQ query I used, but I wasn't able to get things to group properly without [Thomas F's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28964231/1458847). Implementing IEquatable<> on the classes I was grouping by was key.

Thank you all so much! You've taught me a lot with your help on this issue.

Comment: methinks, it's a typo `group alts` and should be `group alt`? and also simple select instead selectmany

Comment: can you show a smaple of what alternative has? Why a list of lists?

Comment: @MichalCiechan You got the basics of what Alternative holds in your answer. As far as why a nested list, that's just what is returned from the service. Basically `List<Claim>` is sent and the service returns `List<Claim>` for each element of the sent list. It's convoluted, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        var alts = alternatives.SelectMany(x => x);

        var res = alts.GroupBy(alt => Tuple.Create(alt.Member, alt.OriginalClaim))
            .Select(g => new Alternative
            {
                Member = g.Key.Item1,
                OriginalClaim = g.Key.Item2,
                AlternativeClaims = g.Select(x => new AlternativeClaim {AltClaim = x.AltClaim, Savings = x.Savings}).ToList()
            });


        foreach (var a in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Auth {0}", a.OriginalClaim.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("MemberId {0}", a.Member.Id);

            foreach (var alt in a.AlternativeClaims.OrderByDescending(c => c.Savings))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tSavings = {0};Id = {1};",alt.Savings, alt.AltClaim.Id);
            }
        }
```

gives output:

```
Auth 51
MemberId 50
    Savings = 696969;Id = 513;
    Savings = 6969;Id = 512;
    Savings = 69;Id = 511;
Auth 52
MemberId 50
    Savings = 1002;Id = 522;
    Savings = 100;Id = 521;
Auth 102
MemberId 100
    Savings = 1022;Id = 1022;
    Savings = 1021;Id = 1021;
```

Test code

```
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var member1 = new Member {Id = 50};
        var member1Claim1 = new Claim {Id = 51};
        var member1Claim2 = new Claim {Id = 52};

        var member2 = new Member { Id = 100 };
        var member2Claim1 = new Claim { Id = 101 };
        var member2Claim2 = new Claim { Id = 102 };

        var alternatives = new List<List<Alt>>()
        {
            new List<Alt>
            {
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member1,
                    OriginalClaim = member1Claim1,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 511},
                    Savings = 69
                },
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member1,
                    OriginalClaim = member1Claim1,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 512},
                    Savings = 6969
                },
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member1,
                    OriginalClaim = member1Claim1,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 513},
                    Savings = 696969
                },
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member1,
                    OriginalClaim = member1Claim2,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 521},
                    Savings = 100
                },
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member1,
                    OriginalClaim = member1Claim2,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 522},
                    Savings = 1002
                }
            },
            new List<Alt>
            {
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member2,
                    OriginalClaim = member2Claim2,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 1021},
                    Savings = 1021
                },
                new Alt
                {
                    Member = member2,
                    OriginalClaim = member2Claim2,
                    AltClaim = new Claim {Id = 1022},
                    Savings = 1022
                }
            }
        };


    }
```

And for completeness:

```
public class Alt
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Claim OriginalClaim { get; set; }
    public Claim AltClaim { get; set; }
    public double Savings { get; set; }
}

public class Claim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Alternative
{
    public Member Member { get; set; }
    public Claim OriginalClaim { get; set; }
    public List<AlternativeClaim> AlternativeClaims { get; set; }
}

public class AlternativeClaim
{
    public Claim AltClaim { get; set; }
    public double Savings { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm fiddling around with my code trying to get this to work. It seems correct, but instead of my results being what you had, I am getting only one AlternativeClaim for each Member and OriginalClaim, so it's printing out the Member/OriginalClaim data for each AlternativeClaim.

I'll keep messing with it and let you know if I get it going.

Comment: I did, but I get the feeling that something weird may be going on with the nested list I get back from the service.

Comment: Key thing is you need to do the SelectMany on alternatives in order to flatten the collection of collections and get a single List<Alt> with all alts.

Comment: maybe because the List of lists is already grouped by an original claim no?

Comment: I wish that were the case, but it's not. It comes back from the service as a list of JSON-formatted list. Using SelectMany is the only way to get to the data and it isn't grouped at all.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely can't get this to work. I have no idea why. No matter how I tweak the code, I end up with Member/OriginalClaim printed with each AlternativeClaim.

Answer (score 1):

Do your Member and Claim classes implement IEquatable?

If not, I suspect the grouping does not work because the Member and Claim instances are being compared by reference. And since you have mentioned that you receive the data from a service as JSON, all of your Alts most likely have distinct Member and Claim instances. Therefore, they never fall into the same group, even if their properties have the same values.

To get your grouping to work, you could do one of the following:

1. If available, choose a unique criterion (like an id or name) from Member and Claim and group by it:

   ```
   var test = from alts in alternatives
              from alt in alts
              group alts by new { MemberId = alt.Member.Id, OriginalClaimId = alt.OriginalClaim.Id } into a
              select a;

   foreach (var a in test)
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Auth {0}", a.Key.OriginalClaimId);
       Console.WriteLine("MemberId {0}", a.Key.MemberId);

       foreach (var alt in a.SelectMany(x => x))
           [write out alt.AltClaim properties in console here]
   }
   ```
2. Implement IEquatable and IEquatable for your Member and Claim.

   ```
   public class Member : IEquatable<Member>
   {
       public bool Equals(Member other)
       {
           return Id == other.Id;
       }

       public override bool Equals(object obj) 
       {
           var other = obj as Member;
           if (other == null)
               return false;

           return Equals(other);
       }

       public override int GetHashCode()
       {
           // Whenever IEquatable is implemented, GetHashCode() must also be overridden.
           return Id.GetHashCode();
       }

       // Rest of the class...
   }
   ```

Comment: This worked 50% of the way (so far). I'll mess with it and see if I can make it work the rest of the way. I have couple of quick questions, though:

(1) In my actual code, there is a combo key in the Member object. The Id notes a unique grouping, but there is secondary identifier in there too. For example, the Member ID is 10099 and the secondary ID could be 01, 02, 03, etc. to note an individual. How would I correctly implement that in the GetHashCode() override? I've currently got it returning `Id.GetHashCode() + secondaryId.GetHashCode()`

(2) [in the next comment, ran out of characters]

Comment: You note that `SelectMany` isn't necessary in the nested `foreach`, but `a` in that case represents `IGrouping<'a,List<Alt>>`. Is there a better way to get into the actual `Alt` object than using `SelectMany`?

Comment: (1) Adding the hashcodes works in a way but is not optimal, since (x,y) results in the same hashcode as (y,x). A simple and often used method to combine the hashcode of two numbes is `Tuple.Create(x, y).GetHashCode()`

Comment: (2) You are right, if its a group of lists, you need the SelectMany(). I have updated the example.

Answer (score 0):

Try `alternatives.SelectMany(alt => new { alt.Member, alt.OriginalClaim })`

Comment: Where at, `var test = `?